# Entity Framework 6 Context usage with Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, moq

I've been working with Entity Framework 6 a lot recently and my team is moving toward a more test driven approach as our code needs to be highly dependable.  We've begun using Moq to write tests for our Data Access and Business Logic Layers.  I'm new to Moq, but we seem to have found a good way to do all of our tests.  However, I have recently run into a two-fold dilemma that I'm not sure how to resolve.

**Project Background:**

Most of our projects are windows services, so that is the example I'll use in this post.  We are using .NET 4.5 with EF6, and SQL Server 2005 (will be upgrading in the future, but we're stuck with this for now).  Moq is version 4.2.1507.118.

**The Dilemma:**

(Short Version:  Entity Framework gets out of sync with real data in DB.)

When using Moq with Entity Framework 6, and writing tests for the DAL, we require a global context defined in the constructor.  The DAL exposes an Interface for Mocking purposes.  This is all well and good.

DAL Constructor for Production:

```
public DbFunctions(ILogger evLog, String contentProvider)
{
    _logger = evLog;
    _contentProvider = contentProvider;
    _myEntities = new MyExampleEntities();
}
```

DAL Constructor for testing only, with Moq:

```
public DbFunctions(MyExampleEntities myEntContext, ILogger log)
{
    _myEntities = myEntContext;
    _logger = log;
    _contentProvider = "Test";
}
```

This test constructor provides us with a way to create a Mock context in our unit tests and not actually call the DB, but use test data we create to verify functionality of the rest of the method.

Next, inside our Business Layer, we create another global variable for our DAL above.

```
_dbFunctions = new DbFunctions(elEventLog, Settings.Default.ContentProvider);
```

This works well, and allows us to call our DAL methods with ease.

One more layer up, and we have our threads, calling our various Business Logic Layers.

```
//Worker thread example
private void MyWorkerThread()
{
    //Log some stuff
    BLLExample bll = new BLLExample();

    do
    {
        //Log stuff
        bll.SomeBLLMethod();
        //Sleep until the next time we want to run (varies)
    } while (true);
}
```

As you can see, with the BLL constructor being created outside the do/while loop, the EF Context can easily get out of sync with the real DB data, since I have other projects that have the ability to modify the same data.  So, my question is, what is the best way to fix this, to keep my ability to use Moq?

I can't simply use

```
MyExampleEntities _fdfEntities = new MyExampleEntities();
```

inside every DAL Method, because that would prevent my ability to use Moq for the DB calls.  I could move

```
BLLExample bll = new BLLExample();
```

inside the do/while loop of the worker thread, but this seems like I shouldn't do that every time.  An alternative is to create a new

```
_dbFunctions = new DbFunctions(elEventLog, Settings.Default.ContentProvider);
```

inside every BLL method, which would work, but will impede us using Moq in Unit Tests for the BLL.  Is there another, more elegant or better way?  Or maybe something with Moq or EF6 that I've missed entirely that would solve my issue?

Comment: So you can use Moq to mock out a context, because everything in a context now is `virtual`

Comment: Updated my post to indicate that I'm using an Interface instead of virtual methods.

Comment: well if you have inherited from the `DbContext`, then you're inheriting virtual methods....

Comment: Bad code smelled.  *DAL Constructor for Production/DAL Constructor for testing only, with Moq* Yeesh.  Best thing to do in your case is to expose your dependencies on the surface of your objects/in your constructor, then use an IoC framework to wire them up.  That way you will be using the same code in your unit tests, but manually spinning up these dependencies with mocks, stubs, etc.